# Debian live-boot squashfs file system discovery

Tags: linux, boot, debian, liveusb

I am building custom lightweight EFI only debian live-boot flash drive. I prepared debian filesystem using debootstrap with installing required packages. Then I packed filesystem to squashfs. I am using syslinux as bootloader. File structure of flash drive (FAT32) is

```
/
├── EFI
│   └── boot
│       ├── bootx64.efi     // this is the same file as syslinux.efi
│       ├── ldlinux.e64
│       ├── syslinux.cfg
│       └── syslinux.efi
└── live
    ├── filesystem.squashfs
    ├── initrd
    └── vmlinuz
```

Content of `syslinux.cfg` is

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 300
DEFAULT deb

LABEL deb
    LINUX /live/vmlinuz
    APPEND boot=live bootfrom=removable-usb
    INITRD /live/initrd
```

Content of `filesystem.squashfs` is petty standard linux filesystem hierarchy containing `/etc`, `/home`, `/root`, `/var` and so on.

But when I boot this image it successfully boot linux and initrd but then it failback to initrd rescue busybox shell. No filesystem is mounted. Note that flash drive is `/dev/sda` and it was properly enumerated by kernel as you can see at the top of picture. Adding/removing `bootfrom=removable-usb` Linux command line parameter have no effect. I followed tutorial [Create a Custom Debian Live Environment (CD or USB) - Will Haley](https://willhaley.com/blog/custom-debian-live-environment/) to make squashfs and then customized it by my requirements (syslinux and efi only).

[image: Boot failure and initrd rescue shell]

My question is how process of searching live file system works and how to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue. While I have filesystem file named `filesystem.squashfs` after copying to FAT32 flashdrive it became `FILESYSTEM.SQUASHFS` and live-boot script is case sensitive when searching for filesystem image. In `/boot.log` which was written if I appended `debug` parameter to Linux command line I found that search was done using following commands.

```
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.squashfs'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.ext2'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.ext3'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.ext4'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.xfs'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.dir'
+ ls '/run/live/medium/live/*.jffs'
```